# Redirect After Selecting dropdown Values

Tags: javascript, json, redirect, github-pages

I am creating a website on github pages so i want user to be directed on fixed page after he choose the final option. I am getting data from JSON file. I also tried to insert  tag to JSON but it is not directing when you click on option edited. The page is here [vaidicbooks.cf/test.html](https://vaidicbooks.cf/test.html)

Comment: you want to redirect the page when user selects the final option which is city ?  If i am correct ?

Comment: You have to write some code to redirect user to any other page on selection of last item. There is no code for `city` change.

Comment: Where you want to redirect to the user on last selection?

Comment: on selecting city say edited it should redirect to name.domain/country/state/city.html

Answer (score 0):

You should add onchange handler for city like -

```
$(document).on('change', '#state', function(){
  var state_id = $(this).val();
  if(state_id != '')
  {
    load_json_data('city', state_id);
  }
  else
  {
    $('#city').html('<option value="">Select city</option>');
  }
}); 

$(document).on('change', '#city', () => {
    var country = $("#country").val();
    var state = $("#state").val();
    var city = $("#city").val();
    window.location.href = `${country}/${state}/${city}.html`;
});
```

and remove HTML onchange handler like -

```
<select name="city" id="city" class="form-control input-lg">
  <option value="">Select city</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thank you, but there is a little error it is not displaying id of the city